# Unable to load the app to appstore from Xcode. Is any solution to solve this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

[image: When I am uploading .ipa to itunesconnect, I am facing this issue]

When I am uploading .ipa to itunesconnect, I am facing this issue... This screenshot is from Xcode -> Window -> Organiser

Comment: try with Application Loader

Comment: It seems there are some files missing in your installation?

Comment: I have removed that directory "mysivana"